# Node / express - require exported js file inside route file

Tags: node.js

I created an app using express generator.  I have a js file in my public/javascripts directory.  I exported an obj:

```
module.exports = { my obj here }
```

Then in my route file (index.js) I've been trying to serve this object as an API so I can fetch it from another js file and do stuff on the front end.

But my require simply won't work. I tried:

```
var specs = require('./javascripts/specs')
```

and all variation of the path cause I assumed that my path was wrong.

Am I missing something obvious? I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/javascripts/specs'......
```

File Structure 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ou9afzckboxbe1w/Screenshot%202018-04-18%2011.59.32.png?dl=0

Comment: Show your directory structure please.

Comment: Done, added file structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `public` folder and your `routes` folder are on the same level in your directory.  Therefore you need to go up to the common parent, then down through `public/javascripts` like this:

```
var specs = require('../public/javascripts/specs');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `public/javascript` is for **client only** scripts, if you want to require it from the server you have to provide the full path :

```
var specs = require('../public/javascripts/specs');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Just tried and got the same error.

Comment: @Lberteh I missed `..` , it's fine now :)